# Instance of class as a Key in LruCache that stores Bitmaps

Tags: java, android

I want to use android LruCache to store bitmaps in memory but I identificate bitmaps by hash, width, height. So I did something like this:

```
class Key {
    private String hash;
    private int widht, height;
}

LruCache<Key, Bitmap> imagesCache = new LruCache<Key, Bitmap>(1024) {
 @Override
    protected int sizeOf(Key key, Bitmap value) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.sizeOf(key, value);
    }
}
```

Is this a proper way and what next ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the `equals` and `hashCode` methods in your class that is used as a key. Make sure, that they are consistent, i.e. when `equals` returns `true`, also `hashCode` must return the same value.

Answer (score 0):

So I have to answered myself. I googled and i found  the Equals and Hash Code article on http://www.javaranch.com/journal/2002/10/equalhash.html and according to it I did something like this:

```
private class Key {
    public Key(String hash, int width, int height, boolean fill) {
        this.hash = hash;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;

        hash = 31 * hash + this.width;
        hash = 31 * hash + this.height;

        return hash;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {

        if(this == obj)
            return true;

        if(obj == null || obj.getClass() != this.getClass())
            return false;

        return this.width == ((Key)obj).width && this.height 
               == ((Key)obj).height && (this.hash == ((Key)obj).hash || 
               (this.hash != null && this.hash.equals(((Key)obj).hash)));
    }
```

Mabey I will be used from someone.